# Find list in nested list with maximum number of highest numbers

Tags: python, max, comparison, nested-lists

I am trying to find the list in nested list, which has the maximum number of highest numbers, as shown bellow:

```
test_list = [[200,1,100],[50,120,0],[40,300,0]]
desired output = [200,1,100]
```

`[200,1,100]` is the winner here, as out of its 3 digits, 2 are higher than the other lists 2 numbers. This would not be sequence sensitive however, for example if:

```
test_list = [[1,100,200],[1,200,100],[200,1,100],[50,120,0],[40,300,0]]
desired output =  [[1,100,200],[1,200,100],[200,1,100]]
```

Reason being that here all three constitue the "maximum" lineup of digits. Is there anyway other than creating all permutations and comparing them?

Edit: For further clarification, for the example above, the numbers in the nested list are 300>200>120>100> 50>40>1. So, which list in the nested list has the maxmimum number of highest numbers? [200,1,100]. Does there exist another list in the nested list, with a higher number of highest numbers? No. If [300,200,1] was in the nested list, it would have won.

To provide context, these are scores for a fuzzy match between a series of strings to find closest matches, each providing 3  scores in a list, in term listed in the list of all possible matches. This is my way of closest match between strings, comparing the fuzzy scores and taking the list with the highest possible scores out of the list.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about why `[200,1,100]` is the winner?

Comment: @martineau unecessary as clearly stated "is there any other way that multiple permutations"

Comment: @El_1988: If true, the OP should have included it in their question.

Comment: @martineau reference to last two lines: " Is there anyway other than creating all permutations and comparing them?"

Comment: @martineau as the question is whether or not there is any other way, attempting to create permutations purely to display here would be confusing to post, and uncecessary waste of time.

Comment: @El_1988: Obviously we don't agree. I can't undo my down-vote now anyway even if I wanted to, so the it's all a moot point.

Comment: Working code wouldn't be confusing, instead it could *clarify* how the question is meant. As the first comment (which you've so far ignored) demonstrates, at least four people found it unclear.

Comment: @superbrain trying to formulate an answer to a question asked doesnt mean it is ignored, please refrain from judging people or their actions. If you read carefully, the  Question asks: "finding the list in the nested list, with the maximum number of highest numbers" . Now, what are the numbers in the nested list? the numbers are 300>200>120>100> 50>40>1. So, which list in the nested list has the maxmimum number of highest numbers? [200,1,100]. Does there exist another list in the nested list, with a higher number of highest numbers? No. If [300,200,1] was in the nested list, it would have won.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find maxes by defining:

- Defining a compare function
- Use the compare function as a key in max

**Code**

```
from functools import cmp_to_key 

def compare(sublist1, sublist2):
    '''
        Comparator function
        
        With >, <, = defined to satisfy the 
        requirements for comparing sublists 
        the function:
        
        Returns:
            Positive when sublist1 > sublist2
            Negative when sublist1 < sublist2
            0        when sublsit1 == sublist2
    '''
    return sum(1 if x > y else -1 for x, y in zip(sorted(sublist1), sorted(sublist2)) if x != y)


def find_max(lst):
    # find max value in list (using custom compare function)
    # use cmp_to_key to key to convert compare function to key
    m = max(lst, key=cmp_to_key(compare))
    
    # Use list comprehension to get all values equal 
    # max (equal when compare(m, x) == 0)
    return [x for x in lst if compare(m, x)==0]
```

**Test**

```
print(find_max([[200,1,100],[50,120,0],[40,300,0]])) 
# Output: [[200, 1, 100]]

print(find_max([[1,100,200],[1,200,100],[200,1,100],[50,120,0],[40,300,0]])) 
# Output [[1, 100, 200], [1, 200, 100], [200, 1, 100]]

print(find_max([[9, 9, 0], [1, 1, 1]])) 
# Output: [[9, 9, 0]]

print(find_max([[100, 100, 44, 100, 100, 56, 38], [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 73], [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 73], [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 56, 41], [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 56, 41], [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 56, 41]] ))
# Output: [[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 73], [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 73]]
```

Comment: thanks very much for the code and response, when input [[100, 100, 44, 100, 100, 56, 38],
 [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 73],
 [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 73],
 [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 56, 41],
 [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 56, 41],
 [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 56, 41]] , for output it yields: [[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 56, 41],
 [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 56, 41],
 [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 56, 41]] ,I expected the answer to be [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 73] , am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @El_1988--updated the algorithm.  Does this produce the desired results?